# Why doesn't Voldemort have a nose?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Is there a particular reason why Voldemort has two slits for a nose in the movie version? Did he lose his actual nose by some way or another?

Comment: "*I say, I say, I say. My Voldemort's got no nose"*. "*Really? How does he smell?"* ***"Terrible!!!"***

Comment: @Richard - possibly related to the question on Voldemort's sex life...